# Get keys from Json with regex Jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I'm hustling with regex, and trying to get the id's from this body. 
But only the id´s in the members list, and not the id in the verified key. :) 
To clarify, I'm using Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter

```
{
  "id": "9c40ffca-0f1a-4f93-b068-1f6332707d02", //<--not this
  "me": {
    "id": "38a2b866-c8a9-424f-a5d4-93b379f080ce",  //<--not this
    "isMe": true,
    "user": {
      "verified": {
        "id": "257e30f4-d001-47b3-9e7f-5772e591970b"  //<--not this
      }
    }
  },
  "members": [
    {
      "id": "88a2b866-c8a9-424f-a5d4-93b379f780ce", //<--this
      "isMe": true,
      "user": {
        "verified": {
          "id": "223e30f4-d001-47b3-9e7f-5772e781970b"  //<--not this
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "53cdc218-4784-4e55-a784-72e6a3ffa9bc", //<--this
      "isMe": false,
      "user": {
        "unverified": {
          "verification": "XYZ"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

at the moment I have this regex :

```
("id": )("[\w-]+")
```

But as you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/NrTh43/2) it returns every guid

Any ideas on how to go on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use programming logic to parse and process the JSON instead. This is not something anyone should be using regular expressions for.

Comment: I suggest to use a language/tool that can parse and access JSON. For example: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: yes indeed. but to clarify. I'm using Jmeter and the Regular Expression Extractor :)

Comment: Why not use a [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter/)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes thanks! good suggestion. Just got it to work with JSON path extractor :)

Comment: With `$.members.[0,1].id`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew $.members[*].id , since it can be unlimited id's :)

Comment: Yeah, `$..members[*].id` works, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the input data type is JSON, it is recommended to use the [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0/).

Once you add it, use the

```
$.members[*].id
```

JSON path expression to match all `id` values of each `members` in the document that are the top nodes.

If you may have nested `memebers`, you may get them all using

```
$..members[*].id
```

You may test these expressions at https://jsonpath.com/, see a test:

[image]